# Why is the gradient the best direction to move in?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, weights

When optimizing a convex function, doing an update like:
$$w_{t+1} =w_{t}+ c\ \nabla(f(w)) $$ is recommended. Why is moving along $\nabla(f(w))$ the fastest way to move closer to the goal? What's the intuition around this?

Comment: Note that you are *maximizing* (optimization can be cast either as maximization or minimization of a target function). So, it's gradient-ascent more than gradient-descent. With respect to your question, think what happens to the function value if you move an *infinitesimally small* step along the gradient.

Comment: you are standing in a field, how would you reach the highest/lowest point in that surface? You take steps towards the direction of the biggest slope... Of course you are not guaranteed to get the global max/min as you can get stuck local minimas/maximas

Comment: The gradient is not necessarily the best direction to move in.  Newton or Quasi-Newton methods are based on a quadratic approximation of the objective function, using the exact or approximate Hessian for the Taylor expansion. Gradient descent is in effect based on this same quadratic approximation, except using the identity matrix in place of the Hessian, which is therefore a less accurate quadratic approximation, and thereby often resulting in an inferior direction.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone: technically, for small enough $\delta$, it's better to move in the direction of the gradient than in the direction dictated by the quadratic approximation used by Newton's method. Of course, the benefit of moving in that direction will degrade quickly, making the Newton's method proposal step a better proposal step than gradient ascent's (i.e. you usually  want your step size to be greater than $\epsilon$). On the other hand, if your step *is* $\epsilon$, you can justify needing to run it in parallel on a server with 30,000 cores!

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Would you agree that it is the best direction if the only information you have available is first derivatives?

Comment: @MatthewDrury: not expect for the first iteration: (ie you only need the first derivatives for BFGS-type algorithms).

Comment: @CliffAB You're right... I must admit, I never really understood how BFGS worked, besides that it has some recursive update for a hessian approximation.

Comment: @Matthew Drury : What CliffAB said. Also note that BFGS is a particular variant (case) of Quasi-Newton, and so was captured in my first comment under "Quasi-Newton" methods.  Actually, while Quasi-Newton methods may be started using the identity matrix as the Hessian approximation, they don't have to, and some times a first iteration can be based on a better approximation to the Hessian than the identity matrix.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Do you have a good reference for intuition on why BGFS works?  I've tried to read a couple of papers/expositions, and I always get quite lost in the details.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone: I'm curious: what are common alternatives? The first one that comes to mind is a diagonal of the Hessian (which you could get very cheaply by computing the gradient twice). Is there any other clever approximations (outside of problem specific approximations)?

Comment: @Matthew Drury No one really knows why BFGS "works". There are various attempted explanations in various papers and books, but ultimately the proof, so to speak, is in the large amount of collective experience that is does "work".  Any by the way, it's not necessarily the best Quasi-Newton method by any means in many circumstances, but that's a whole complicated subject.

Comment: @ Cliff AB , a prior knowledge, which could exist for any number of reasons (in fact you might even exactly compute the Hessian or by finite difference of gradients just for the first iteration), possibly in the form of some scalar multiple of the identity matrix.  Another technique is to use identity for first "step", but scale that initial "Hessian" to match approximate dominant eigenvalue before applying first Quasi-Newton update, which might help speed up getting a "good" Hessian approximation.

Comment: FWIW, there are (infinitely) differentiable strictly convex functions $f$ on compact strictly convex domains $X$ for which there exists a point $x\in X$ at which the gradient $Df(x)$ points *directly opposite* the direction $x^{*}-x$ from $x$ to the (unique) maximum $x^{*}$ of $f$. In this sense $Df(x)$ takes one *away* from the goal in the "fastest" way possible. This shows why requests to clarify the meaning of "fastest" should be taken seriously.

Comment: @whuber , can you give an example of such a "directly opposite" case? That might help formulate interesting algorithm test cases.

Answer (score 6):

**Your questions were:**

1. Why is moving along $\nabla \left( f\left(x \right ) \right )$ the fastest way to move closer to the
   goal?
2. What's the intuition around this?

They are not the same question.  A solid answer for the second, imo, leads to better engagement on the use, and on the first part.  It is also more accessible for someone trying to get the basics down reasonably well.

**My answers are, in reverse order:**

**(Answer 2)** The intuition driving this is "steepest ascent".  It is an assumption.

Some insight on going along the steepest direction can be seen in here:
[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographic_prominence]

This is from the "[Topographic prominence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographic_prominence)" page on Wikipedia.

If you start near the bottom of Atkins hill, and want to take the fewest number of steps* to get to the top, then the steepest slope is a good approach.  By "*" I mean that a step is a projection on the topographical map.  It does not account for vertical distance, and assumes that if you want to be at some place, you can.  This is good for functions, but can take work when climbing mountains.

If, on the other hand, you start at the top of Atkins hill, and use gradient ascent, then you don't go to Great Pond Mountain.  You only stay where you are.  The "gradient" doesn't give you a direction to go.

We like the gradient "where you are" on mathematical surfaces, because it can be computed or approximated.  This is especially useful in places like neural networks or deep belief networks where the location of our destination peak isn't knowable when we start in on the problem.  Finding it isn't easy, but we have computers to compute many many gradients while looking for the optimal configuration of parameters.

Some ways to handle the weakness of the intuition include:

- multiple uniformly randomly located initial points, and record the
  location and value of the highest result.
- Another is called simulated annealing.
- Conjugate gradient ascent isn't bad, it will get you to the peak of a
  parabola quicker.
- Over and under-relaxation can also accelerate convergence.

Like many things in math, and also like many things in the human experience, it is not a bad initial assumption, it is false but useful, and with time and work you can overcome its weaknesses.

**(Answer 1)** For your question 1, the "why" is a more challenging answer.

It is more symbolically intensive.  One must talk about convex, and distance measures.  There are derivatives and such.

One must also talk about what "fast" means.  The fewest steps is zero, and the only way to do that is to start there.  The second fewest is to know where it is, and take one step to get there.

There is a rule in optimal control that says "best" doesn't mean anything without a rubric.  If you say an approach is best, then the rubric can often be pulled out of the answer.  If you provide the problem and the rubric, then the approach that serves that rubric (assuming it exists) can often be determined.  We could show the rubric's under which this approach is "best".

Fastest can mean different things.  Do you mean fewest mathematical operations?  Shortest time given an infinite supercomputer?  Fast isn't strongly defined and I don't want to presume too much on your question.

Can you clarify what you are looking for in part (1) of your questions?

**Update:**
Using the method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), the extremal values occur at [critical points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)) on the surface.  If you assume that you started "near enough" to one of the critical points then by moving to points that reduce the gradient at your location to zero, you move to the critical points. "Near enough", though hand-wavey, usually lets Taylor Series assumptions convert your surface to being locally quadratic.

Comment: This contour map does not represent a convex function--which was one of the stipulations of the question.  That seems to have taken you off on a tangent which does not address the question.

Comment: The goal is not necessarily convex.  The asker seems to understand that gradient descent/ascent works on convex functions, but is asking why the general approach is valid.  They are asking about intuition, not proof.

Comment: (+1) The edits are a remarkable improvement: thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It's easiest to think about this first in 1D. If you're trying to minimize a function, and you know it decreases to the left and increases to the right, which direction would go in? Clearly, you would want to go left (especially if you knew that there was only one local min, as implied by convexity).

Now consider moving in higher dimensions. The first issue is what direction are we going to move in? Well, the concept of *directional derivatives* is required to make an informed decision. The basic idea is that the derivative of moving in a line in any direction is

$ \nabla f(x) \cdotp u$

Where $u$ is the unit vector describing the direction. What is the value that minimizes this? $u = -\nabla f(x)$. Therefore, stepping in the direction *opposite* of the gradient vector is the direction that will mostly quickly reduce your objective function. Of course, this is only the steepest direction in a very tight neighborhood, so as Mark Stone points out, it is *not* necessarily an optimal way to chose a proposal step.

Comment: An interesting addition would be some intuition for why the directional derivative is linear in the direction, i.e., why it is a dot product.

Comment: @MatthewDrury: is it sufficient if I answer "because Real Analysis"?

Comment: (+1) @Matthew As you well know, *by definition* the derivative is linear. If there is any analytical content to this question, it would be in the form of "Given $\epsilon\gt 0$, let $u(\epsilon)$ be a unit direction in which $f(w_t+\epsilon u)$ is maximized. Show that $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}} u(\epsilon) = Df(w_t)/||Df(w_t)||$$ if $f$ is differentiable at $w_t$ and has nonzero derivative $Df(w_t)$ there."

Comment: Agreed.  But that's a definition (the derivative is the linear mapping that satisfies...) that comes rather later in people's mathematical education than the directional derivative/gradient definitions.  Also, since the question was asked for more intuition than rigour, I thought that possible we could offer that here.  You know, something like the tangent plane to the graph, lines in the tangent plane.  I'm also +1, I think it's a fine answer as is.

Comment: @CliffAB  That the direction in which we get the fastest change is the same as that of $\nabla f(x)$ was not obvious to me. If we solve : $max_{\bar{u}} \bar{a}.\bar{u}$ where $\bar{u}$ is a unit vector it turns out that when $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{u}$ are collinear the dot product will be maximum. Replacing $\bar{a}$ with $\nabla f(x)$ convinced me

Answer (score 3):

For a simple, ***intuitive*** answer to your question, which is what you wanted:

**You are more likely to find the sea by going downhill whenever you can, than by going uphill or by ignoring the gradient altogether!**

That's exactly what water does, and why most of it ends up in the sea.

However, that is not always the case, as it could get stuck in a local lake or reservoir.  It all depends on the topography of your function, and whether there are any local minima that could act as traps, and whether there are any escape routes from those traps, like the rivers that lead from a lake into the sea.

Also, water will take a very indirect, meandering path around a hill, rather than the shortest path over the hill.

But still, if you want to find the sea as quickly as possible, then it's usually best to keep going downhill whenever you can.  Follow the gradient.  Follow the water.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a short, intuitive answer.** For any continuously-differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto\mathbb{R}$, the gradient vector evaluated at a point $x$, written $\nabla f(x)$, captures (amongst other things) the *direction* of maximal *instantaneous* change upwards. This is just one of the properties of derivatives. Take a simple parabola $f(x) = x^2$, $\nabla f(3) = 6$ points towards $+\infty$ (so the direction is positive). Similarly, $\nabla f(-3) = -6$ points towards $-\infty$ (so the direction is negative). Even at $x=-3$, the direction towards $+\infty$ is still going to result in function increase if you go *far enough*, but it's not the direction of instantaneous increase. Thus, in both cases, the derivative points towards the direction the function will increase most given where you're currently located.

Since the function is continuously differentiable (meaning $\nabla f$ is a continuous mapping) the direction of maximal instantaneous rate of change is exactly opposite the direction of maximal instantaneous decrease. So whichever way the gradient tells you to go, going the exact other way will necessarily provide instantaneous decrease (given the assumptions I stated).

The practical reason why we take the direction of instantaneous decrease as a good proxy for *the direction pointing to the minima* is simply because we don't know how the whole function looks (especially in higher-dimensions) to be able to say "the minima is over here" or "over there." If we did know where the minima is, then there's no reason to optimize (the problem is solved already).

**Conclusion.** Gradient descent is a way to keep decreasing the function value. Given the function is unimodal (i.e. quasiconvex), of which convex is a special case, we will necessarily *get to where we want to go*. In fact, even if it isn't quasiconvex, [recent work out of UC Berkeley](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04915v2.pdf) shows that, with random initialization, gradient descent will produce at least a local minimizer (not a saddle point) with probability one.

[image: A Bird's Eye View of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto\mathbb{R}$]

Comment: Re: "This is just how derivatives are defined."  That would be an unusual definition in my experience--I have never seen the derivative defined like this--so could you offer a reference?  And why the emphasis on "continuously differentiable"? That seems unnecessary to support the implications you are drawing. In your conclusion, where does "probability" come in? That's not part of the apparatus of functions, derivatives, or continuity.

Comment: @whuber changed the first part, good catch. For continuously-differentiable, I believe there are edge-cases when the gradient is a step-function or a function with kinks. In this case, the gradient may be the direction of maximal increase, while the negative gradient may not necessarily be a descent direction.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  But doesn't your change now beg the question?  Exactly why (intuitively and mathematically) does the derivative have this maximal property you claim of it?